# Spring Cloud Data Flow: Communication between Custom app Stream and pre-built app Stream

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Hi guys,
I have a problem with Spring Cloud Data Flow. I can’t transfer data between a pre-built application stream and a custom application.

ENVIRONMENT:
Kafka version:  0.10.2.1 (with the 2.11 scala version)
Spring Cloud Data Flow version: 1.5.0
Spring boot version: 2.0.2

PROBLEMS:

I've done the tuto from :  https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_custom_processor_application 
then I've registered a custom app named transformer (processor type).

[picture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Zz2Th7Jm7OLb5cMXL8PfvgON5xlYZtic)




 
I create a stream and I deploy it using my custom app.


- problem 1: The deployment of the custom application stream never ends.

[picture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13GaqXhpM3xd6tQP7vijhQIMQAvZ1ZEUX)


- problem 2 : I can't transfert data between a pre-built application stream and a custom application.

Here is the stdout of transormer app:
 [picture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G20Qvv21T-XVZHy9TJl2mWhaM4uO1Bki) 



Here is the stdout of the log (sink):
[picture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1If0uyMcdwWw_JhZZstUj6IgLpK_2YpO8)

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:
- I have also tried this but same problems ->[Custom Stream Cloud Processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_custom_spring_cloud_stream_processor)
- I have tried a lot of other tutos from other sites..
- I have tried different versions of kafka: 1.1.0, 1.0.1

- I have read the documentation of Spring Cloud Stream and the documentation of Spring Cloud Data Flow,
but I can't tell what is wrong with what I did.

Thank you in advance for the help you will bring.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds rude, it's not meant to be, but linking to images of code and/or error messages is bad enough and you are linking to images of code/error messages of pictures hosted at Google Docs. This makes it really hard to gather all the information to understand your question. Please post all relevant code and error messages _as text_ into the question, and if you want to add images for other purposes, use the provided functionality for that instead of linking to Google Docs. And also, please use Markdown instead of HTML to format your post, wherever possible.

Comment: Ok I'll take your suggestions into account. I couldn't use Stackoverflow functionality to post images because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Alright, I wasn't aware of the fact that you need some minimum rep to use the image functionality at all. Still, it's really not a good idea to use images for code. If you are interested, you can read more about that here: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me to resolve the problem.

With the 2.0.2 version of Spring, my custom application stream didn't work. But when I used the 1.5.13 version of Spring, everything worked !

I hope it will help some people.

Answer (score 0):

The logs attached as images are not very useful. If you still have it handy, it'd be good to review the actual logs. You can edit the original post with backticks or upload the logs as gist and link it.

From what I can tell, you're attempting to run the 2.x Stream App against the old Kafka broker. It should still show up in the logs as errors, though, so reviewing the specifics would help troubleshoot it.

Also, here's the Stream and Kafka [compatibility matrix](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/wiki/Kafka-Client-Compatibility) for your reference.